# Applying compute/kernel function to vertex buffer before vertex shader

Tags: swift, shader, metal, compute-shader, metalkit

I would like to use a compute shader to modify my vertices before they are passed to the vertex shader. I can’t find any examples or explanations of this, except that it seems to be mentioned here: [Metal emulate geometry shaders using compute shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50557224/metal-emulate-geometry-shaders-using-compute-shaders). This doesn’t help me as it doesn’t explain the CPU part of it.

I have seen many examples where a texture buffer is read and written to in a compute shader, but I need to read and modify the vertex buffer, which contains custom vertex structs with normals, and is created by a MDLMesh. I would be forever grateful for some sample code!

**BACKGROUND**

What I actually want to achieve is really to be able to modify the vertex normals on the GPU. The other option would be if I could access the entire triangle from the vertex shader, like in the linked answer. For some reason I can only access a single vertex, using the stage_in attribute. Using the entire buffer does not work for me in this particular case, this is probably related to using a mesh provided by Model I/O and MDLMesh. When I create the vertices manually I am able to access the vertex buffer array. Having said that, with that solution I would have to calculate the new vertex normal vector three time for each triangle which seems wasteful, and in any case I want to be able to apply compute shaders to the vertex buffer!

Comment: At some point, you've set up the `vertexDescriptor` of your Metal render pipeline, right? You've also set up the buffers that correspond to the layouts of that vertex descriptor. You're going to have to use those to access the vertex data directly. I don't think there's any easy way to do what you want. You could convert the `vertexDescriptor` to a `stageInputDescriptor` for a compute pipeline, but then you still will only see one vertex at a time.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Sure, I have figured out that if I DONT use the vertexdescriptor that the metalkit mesh makes, then I can ditch the stage_in and get access to the entire buffer in Metal, so that solution works now, but it’s pretty wasteful since I need to do my calculations 3 or 4 times per vertex, and not very flexible. What I really want to do is read the vertex buffer in a compute kernel, modify them and write to a second buffer or similar, and then read the adjusted vertex buffer in the vertex shader, but all the examples I’ve found modify a texture2d in the compute shader.

Comment: There's no problem modifying a buffer in a compute shader. Just have it take a parameter like `device VertexIn *buffer [[buffer(0)]]`. Then, in the function, just read and/or write `buffer[vertexIndex].field`. You'd typically compute the vertex index from the grid position (maybe as simple as one-to-one for a one-dimensional compute "grid").

Comment: OK, I thought that it wasn’t possible to write to vertex buffers on ”tier 1” devices. Also, in cases where they write to textures in kernel functions they seem to pass in a reference with access::read and write to another one with access::write, is that not needed for vertex buffers? I’m also concerned that metal will make sure that a particular vertex is not sent to the vertex shader until after it’s been in the compute shader. Ideally I’d like to modify vertices in batches of 4, since each vertex in a quad should have the same adjusted normal! Do you have any example code lying around?

Comment: You seem to be confusing buffers and textures. Kernel and vertex functions have always been able to read and write buffers. There are limitations on fragment functions writing to buffers. Also, writing to *textures* in graphics functions has limitations. With respect to vertex buffers, there's nothing special to Metal about them. They're just buffers like any other. There's no worry about a race on the GPU between the compute shader and rendering commands. No example code lying around. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Ken Thomases' comments, I managed to find a solution. He made me realise it is quite straightforward:

I'm using a vertex struct that looks like this:

```
// Metal side
struct Vertex {
    float4 position;
    float4 normal;
    float4 color;
};

// Swift side
struct Vertex {
    var position: float4
    var normal: float4
    var color: float4
}
```

During setup where I usually create a vertex buffer, index buffer and render pipeline state, I now also make a compute pipeline state:

```
// Vertex buffer
let dataSize = vertexData.count*MemoryLayout<Vertex>.stride
vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: vertexData, length: dataSize, options: [])!

// Index buffer
indexCount = indices.count
let indexSize = indexCount*MemoryLayout<UInt16>.stride
indexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: indices, length: indexSize, options: [])!

// Compute pipeline state
let adjustmentFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "adjustment_func")!
cps = try! device.makeComputePipelineState(function: adjustmentFunction)

// Render pipeline state
let rpld = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
rpld.vertexFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "vertex_func")
rpld.fragmentFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "fragment_func")
rpld.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
rps = try! device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: rpld)

commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()!
```

Then my render function looks like this:

```
let black = MTLClearColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
rpd.colorAttachments[0].texture = drawable.texture
rpd.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = black
rpd.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear

let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()!

let computeCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()!
computeCommandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(cps)
computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
computeCommandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(MTLSize(width: meshSize*meshSize, height: 1, depth: 1), threadsPerThreadgroup: MTLSize(width: 4, height: 1, depth: 1))
computeCommandEncoder.endEncoding()

let renderCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: rpd)!
renderCommandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(rps)
renderCommandEncoder.setFrontFacing(.counterClockwise)
renderCommandEncoder.setCullMode(.back)

updateUniforms(aspect: Float(size.width/size.height))
renderCommandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
renderCommandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(uniformBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
renderCommandEncoder.setFragmentBuffer(uniformBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
renderCommandEncoder.drawIndexedPrimitives(type: .triangle, indexCount: indexCount, indexType: .uint16, indexBuffer: indexBuffer, indexBufferOffset: 0)
renderCommandEncoder.endEncoding()

commandBuffer.present(drawable)
commandBuffer.commit()
```

Finally my compute shader looks like this:

```
kernel void adjustment_func(const device Vertex *vertices [[buffer(0)]], uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
    vertices[gid.x].position = function(pos.xyz);
}
```

and this is the signature of my vertex function:

```
vertex VertexOut vertex_func(const device Vertex *vertices [[buffer(0)]], uint i [[vertex_id]], constant Uniforms &uniforms [[buffer(1)]])
```

Comment: What is `meshSize` in this case?